# bizarre probleme with csv file

Tags: batch-file

im having a very weird problem with my csv files.
I try to get as output the data before the first coma, it works with every files except one.

it's this one (with different alias and name ofc)

```
dbackup_support,Support AdBackup,0
admin.zoom,admin.zoom,0
Administrateur,Administrateur,0
jsmith,john smith,266
jsmith1,john smith1,266
jsmith1,john smith1,12
jsmith1,john smith1,4232
jsmith1,john smith1,243
jsmith1,john smith1,532524
```

so with this code :

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%A in (Liste_mailboxes.txt) do (
    set var1=%%A
    echo !var1!
    pause
)
pause
```

it wont even go in the loop

while with this file it wiill work

```
jsmith1,23/10/2017 20:58 
jsmith2,23/10/2017 21:00 
jsmith3,23/10/2017 20:59 
jsmith4,23/10/2017 21:15 
jsmith5,23/10/2017 21:26 
jsmith6,23/10/2017 21:05 
jsmith7,23/10/2017 21:47
```

do you have any idea what i have done wrong ? thank you and sorry for bad english

edit : i have found more weird thing, if i copy past what is in the file into a new one it will work. But if i do a copy of it, it wont work. I really dont know whats wrong with this file.

Comment: are you sure the file encoding is not UTF-8?

Comment: i just found it was in utf16 thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, your first text file has a Unicode encoding. Some batch commands (like `for`) do have problems with that. `Type` converts the encoding to Ansi "on the fly", so you can:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%A in ('type Liste_mailboxes.txt') do (
    set var1=%%A
    echo !var1!
    pause
)
```

Note if you don't to anything to `var`, you can just use `%%A` instead:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%A in ('type Liste_mailboxes.txt') do (
    echo %%A
    pause
)
```

Comment: thank you, i found out it was in utf16 and i have to enconding it to ansi